# Is there any options that I can load graphs through api calls in grafana?

Tags: grafana

Is there any options that I can load graphs through API calls? I want to load graphs without any data source. For each graph I want to assign different endpoints of API. is there any way to do that?

Comment: what is data format you're trying to send over API call? like prometheus metric, json data?

Comment: we will send json data through our backend server.

Comment: I know this isn't what you want, but take a look on this plugin, https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/simpod-json-datasource

Comment: If I have different panels(graphs) in a single dashboard. How we can manage with different data sets. is there any option that we can send input to determine what data to send for which graph?